# How to let Experience Manager load correct news article page in DXA

Tags: web8, dxa, experience-manager

After install DXA, we want to create a new News Article, which we follow the process be introduced here: [Adding a News Article Page](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-86264216-4AB2-4769-B840-B54BD83C19AB&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-86264216-4AB2-4769-B840-B54BD83C19AB.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-86264216-4AB2-4769-B840-B54BD83C19AB)

The page can be created success, but the URL inside the Experience Manager is wrong. It use: http://dxaexample.ubi.com/articles/news/MyNews1.html, but the correct link should be http://dxaexample.ubi.com/articles/news/MyNews1, without the file extension.

How can we let Experience Manager understand current DXA site route configure and use the correct URL?

Comment: Pages in Tridion always have an extension - so Experience Manager is just using the URL as stored in Tridion. You may have to implement a redirect for this.

Comment: Thanks Nuno for your info. Does it mean we will always face 404 error inside the Experience Manager if we follow this doc to create new article inside DXA site, unless we implement our own redirect logic here?

Comment: Also could you please detail a bit what kind of redirect we could add here?

Comment: Although DXA supports extensionless URLs, it should handle URLs with .html extension just fine. Which exact SDL Web version are you using?

Comment: Current version is SDL WEB 8.1

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in XPM 8.1.0 which resulted in such problems when creating new Pages. This has been fixed in XPM 8.1.1 (aka Web 8 CU 1). See http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-6ADBA0DA-7419-4888-99E6-3D6EE9787A09

Above topic mentions the official solution to the problem: upgrade to SDL Web 8 CU 1.
An older version of the topic also mentioned work-around: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-6ADBA0DA-7419-4888-99E6-3D6EE9787A09

Comment: This could solve the URL issue, but we still face another 404 error. The URL is correct, for somehow, it always show 404 first, then after 1 to 2 seconds, if we refresh the same URL again, the page will load. Is it because the XPM try to load a page when its publish not be finished yet?

Comment: XPM Session Preview should be used to immediately show the new Page (even before its published). Is XPM Session Preview working properly (i.e. do you see the changes you make in XPM after you press the Update Preview button)?